# How fix type mismatch using tail recursion?

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming

I need to group one list into two by index numbers, if it odd to first list, if even to second.

Here is my function

```
def group2(list: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = {
  def group2Helper(list: List[Int], listA: List[Int], listB: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = list match {
    case Nil => (listA, listB)
    case head :: tail => group2Helper(tail.tail, listA ::: List(head), listB ::: List(tail.head))
 }
}

group2(List(2, 6, 7, 9, 0, 4, 1))
```

As result it have to return (List(2, 7, 0, 1), List(6, 9, 4))

Now I have problem: "Type mismatch, found: Unit, required: (List[Int], List[Int])", that highlighted at last brace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you fix the missing `group2helper()` invocation your code still won't work because you're processing the input two at a time, but the input `List` has an odd number of elements so that will cause a runtime error.

A different approach is to process the input one at a time and keep swapping which list gets added to.

```
def group2(list: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = {
  def group2Helper(list: List[Int], listA: List[Int], listB: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = list match {
    case Nil => (listA.reverse, listB.reverse)
    case hd :: tl => group2Helper(tl, listB, hd :: listA)
  }
  group2Helper(list, Nil, Nil)
}

group2(List(2, 6, 7, 9, 0, 4, 1))
//res0: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(6, 9, 4),List(2, 7, 0, 1))
```

Two things worth noting: 1) When building a `List` it is often more efficient to pre-pend (i.e. build it backwards) and then reverse the result, and 2) the order of the output lists will depend on whether the input has an even or odd number of elements, but the content of each output `List` will be correct.

---

OK, so there's a simple fix for the order-of-output-lists problem.

```
def group2(list: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = {
  def group2Helper(list: List[Int], listA: List[Int], listB: List[Int]): (List[Int], List[Int]) = list match {
    case Nil          => (listA.reverse, listB.reverse)
    case hd :: Nil    => ((hd::listA).reverse, listB.reverse)
    case a :: b :: tl => group2Helper(tl, a::listA, b::listB)
  }
  group2Helper(list, Nil, Nil)
}
```

This is a return to the original two-at-a-time processing, but with two different termination patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was really cool solving. But it have one error, when you have odd number of elements, lists changes between: with odd indexes making second and with even first

Comment: @Ilya; Did you read what I wrote? I told _you_ about the order-of-out-lists issue. I didn't bother to fix it since you had already marked this question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

`group2` defines a function, but doesn't actually execute it. After you define `group2helper`, make sure you call it and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, I just forgot about this)